# Kibana Embedded Dashboard Not Logging In after Enabling X-pack security plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am Wroking with ELK Stack 7.x version, Here I am trying to Embed Dashboard to another html page but I am not able to loggin into embedded dashboard since i configured x-pack security plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure the [Anonymous access](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kibana-authentication.html#anonymous-authentication)

```
xpack.security.authc.providers:
  anonymous.anonymous1:
    order: 0
    credentials:
      username: "anonymous_service_account"
      password: "anonymous_service_account_password"
```

> Anyone with access to the network Kibana is exposed to will be able to
> access Kibana. Make sure that you’ve properly restricted the
> capabilities of the anonymous service account so that anonymous users
> can’t perform destructive actions or escalate their own privileges.

Comment: Thanks - but already we configured x-pack security plugin, when i am trying to add anonymous user configuration it's not working.